# In Corona SDK the background image always cover other images

Tags: coronasdk

I'm currently making a tower defense game with Corona SDK. However, while I'm making the gaming scene, The background scene always cover the monster spawn, I've tried `background:toBack()` ,however it's doesn't work.Here is my code:

```
module(..., package.seeall)

function new()
    local localGroup = display.newGroup();

    local level=require(data.levelSelected);

    local currentDes = 1;

    monsters_list = display.newGroup()

    --The background
    local bg = display.newImage ("image/levels/1/bg.png");
    bg.x = _W/2;bg.y = _H/2;
    bg:toBack();

    --generate the monsters
    function spawn_monster(kind)
        local monster=require("monsters."..kind);
        newMonster=monster.new()
        --read the spawn(starting point) in level, and spawn the monster there
        newMonster.x=level.route[1][1];newMonster.y=level.route[1][2];
        monsters_list:insert(newMonster);
        localGroup:insert(monsters_list);
        return monsters_list;
    end

    function move(monster,x,y)
        -- Using pythagoras to calauate the moving distace, Hence calauate the time consumed according to speed
        transition.to(monster,{time=math.sqrt(math.abs(monster.x-x)^2+math.abs(monster.y-y)^2)/(monster.speed/30),x=x, y=y, onComplete=newDes})
    end

    function newDes()
        currentDes=currentDes+1;
    end

    --moake monster move according to the route
    function move_monster()
        for i=1,monsters_list.numChildren do
            move(monsters_list[i],200,200);
            print (currentDes);
        end 

    end

    function agent()
        spawn_monster("basic");
    end

    --Excute function above.
    timer2 = timer.performWithDelay(1000,agent,10);
    timer.performWithDelay(100,move_monster,-1);
        timer.performWithDelay(10,update,-1);
    move_monster();

    return localGroup;
end
```

and the monster just stuck at the spawn point and stay there.
[image]

but, When i comment these 3 lines of code:

```
--local bg = display.newImage ("image/levels/1/bg.png");
--bg.x = _W/2;bg.y = _H/2;
--bg:toBack();
```

The problem disappear
[image]

Any ideas??Thanks for helping

Comment: Perhaps you are spawning the background multiple times? Try adding `print("spawned")` right after spawning the background to check. Just an idea, probably isn't the solution.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work, Anyway ,Thanks for your advice!

Comment: The question is still a good one; this problem happens to everyone.  But the accepted answer is out of date.  Corona Labs [introduced the Composer API for scene management](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) in 2014. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42976328/6286781) updates the accepted answer for Composer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using director,  you should insert all your display objects into the localGroup. 
You haven't inserted bg into localGroup.

SO director class inserts bg finally after inserting localGroup.

Modify your code as

```
    --The background

    local bg = display.newImage (localGroup,"image/levels/1/bg.png");
    bg.x = _W/2;bg.y = _H/2;
    bg:toBack();
```

or add the code

```
 localGroup:insert(bg)
```

Comment: Thank very much for your advice! It's work, After I have 15 reputation, I'll vote up for you!

Comment: sure! No worries. 
You can accept the answer in the mean time :)

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Corona SDK:

> Composer is the official scene (screen) creation and management library in Corona SDK.... The primary object in the Composer library is the `scene` object...and it contains a unique `self.view`.... This `self.view` is where you should insert visual elements pertaining to the scene.

So now in your `scene:create()` method, you should insert all DisplayObjects into `self.view`. It looks like this:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

function scene:create()

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local bg = display.newImage( ...
    bg.x, bg.y = ...

    local dude = display.newImage( ...
    dude.x, dude.y = ....

    sceneGroup:insert(bg)
    sceneGroup:insert(dude)

end
```

The layering of DisplayObjects in this `sceneGroup` depends on the order in which they are added to the group, with the object added last on top.  You can control this ordering with the `toBack()` and `toFront()` methods.